# Как сделать чтоб бот брал id новых сообщений?

Tags: python, discord.py

У меня есть вот этот код и мне нужно сделать так чтобы бот мог брать айди егоже сообщения.
Как это сделать?

````
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="r!")


my_channel = None
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Я готов к труду и обороне!')
    global my_channel
    my_channel = bot.get_channel(id)


@bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    message_id = payload.message_id
    if message_id == message:
        guild_id = payload.guild_id
        guild = discord.utils.find(lambda g: g.id == guild_id, bot.guilds)

        if payload.emoji.name == 'x':
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='Bumber')
        else:
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name=payload.emoji.name)

    if role is not None:
        member = discord.utils.find(
            lambda m: m.id == payload.user.id, guild.members)
        if member is not None:
            await member.add_roles(role)
            print('test')
        else:
            print('error')
    else:
        print('Role not found...')

    

@bot.command()
async def reg(ctx, tmname, tmtag, tmnam, play=' '):
    author = ctx.message.author

    await ctx.send(f'{author}. Вы зарегистрировали компанию...')
    modreport = bot.get_channel(879596645820555344)
    test = bot.get_channel(942074673624125480)

    # Напишите нам мы всегда ответим на ваш вопрос быстро.
    msg = await modreport.send(f'{author} имеет это  {tmname} {tmtag} {tmnam}, {play} ')
    await msg.add_reaction("✅")
    await msg.add_reaction("❌")


bot.run("bla-bla-bla")```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто запишите объект сообщения в переменную при отправке

```py
message = await ctx.send('text')
```

А затем используйте как обычно:

```py
message.id
```

Comment: Спасибо, очень помог